# SocketStream: conditionally loading Stylus files?

Tags: javascript, node.js, stylus

How would I go about doing something like using x.styl for one part of my app and y.styl for another part?

It seems that all css is contained in app.styl and I can't conditionally load sheets depending on content. Am I suppose to handel this via conditional statements within stylus or via JS?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't use jade for this in SocketStream since all assets are loaded initially. An asset manager is coming in 0.4 that will achieve what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

You should handle this outside of stylus in your HTML (or whatever templating language you use for HTML).  For example, in a jade template you could do:

```
- var style = 'x.css'
- if (mainArea)
  - style = 'y.css'
link(href=style, type="text/css", rel="stylesheet")
```

You would render this by passing in a boolean called `mainArea` via your jade `locals` option when rendering the template.